# SOQL Injection Vulnerability question

Tags: apex, soql

I am looking at some of the classes that are written and I am confused if this soql is vulnerable or not.

I understand that anything with **'%' + searchTerm + '%'** is issue for [soql injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_sql_injection.htm), but how about if I have something like this.

```
query  = searchquery + ' AND (someObject.field3 like \'' + searchStr + '%\'';
query  = searchquery + ' OR someObject.field1 like \'' + searchStr + '%\'';
query  = searchquery + ' OR someObject.field2  like \'' + searchStr + '%\' )';
```

Does this call SOQL Injection? if so how do you fix it? Sorry completely confused when it is not and when it's soql injection.

By the way, searchStr is user input field.

Comment: I read that post but that didn't answer my question. How can I tell if \'' + searchStr + '%\' is the soql injection problem.

Comment: From the doc linked in the above Q&A: _SQL/SOQL injection takes user-supplied input and uses those values in a dynamic SOQL query. If the input isn’t validated, it can include SOQL commands that effectively modify the SOQL statement and trick the application into performing unintended commands_

Comment: Unless you use a binding variable, any string input for use in a filter in the query is a potential source of attack and must therefore be escaped. This includes labels and label translations according to Salesforce Security review.

Comment: That make sense. Thank you!